# Relaciones en BD

Tags: sql, base-de-datos, postgresql

Hola tengo una pregunta sobre una relación y quisiera saber si esta es una manera errónea o hay alguna mejor forma este son tablas de ejemplos supongamos que se crea un post y este post pueden tener muchos comments y también puede tener muchos response, pero los comments solo pueden tener un response. **MI duda es si la clave table_post_id es redundante ya que esta en el comment así como el response**

**TABLE_POST**
  id
  name

**TABLE_COMMENT**
  table_post_id
  table_response_id
  comment

**TABLE_RESPONSE**
 table_post_id
 response

Comment: ¿Qué diferencia hay entre un **Comment** y un **Response** en un **Post** y como se diferenciarían?

Comment: A ver, para entenderte, un **POST** puede tener muchos **COMMENT** y un **COMMENT** puede tener un solo **RESPONSE** ???

Answer (score 1):

Es una relación interesante, la puedes manejar de la siguiente forma:

```
        **POST**
        ID_POST
        NAME

        **COMMENT**
        ID
        COMMENT

        **RESPONSE**
        ID
        RESPONSE
```

Y una tabla que los relacione a todos

```
        **TABLA_RELACION**
        ID_PROPIO//ES OPCIONAL
        ID_POST
        ID_COMMENT
        ID_RESPONSE
```

Ahora, si un comment solo puede tener un response define una **UNIQUE KEY** compuesta entre ID_COMMENT y ID_RESPONSE en la tabla de relación.

Espero te sirva!